# Get user profile facebook using oficial facebook-android-sdk

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

i am using facebook-android-sdk for a single sign on, but i can`t get user facebook profile data. this is my code:

```
try {
            JSONObject me = new JSONObject(facebook.request("me"));
            String id = me.getString("id");
            String name = me.getString("name");
            System.out.println("Id: " + id + "  ---- " + name);
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
```

How get user data profile?
Thanks you!

Comment: I believe this IS a valid question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that you logged in.

```
AsyncFacebookRunner myAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
myAsyncRunner.request("me", new meRequestListener());
```

The request listener:

```
public class meRequestListener implements RequestListener() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        //response is your JSON response
    }

    //You also have to override all the other methods
}
```

Comment: Works fine with your solution thanks BananaNutTruffles

Comment: Perfectly code working very well and no bugs or issues Thanks!!!!